# Obtain Oracle 11g partitioning interval by direct system table query

Tags: oracle, partitioning

I've got a table which is partitioned on a NUMBER variable in Oracle 11g, with the INTERVAL set to 1.  On our development system I can execute

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE', 'TABLE_NAME', 'SCHEMA_NAME') FROM DUAL;
```

to verify that the table is partitioned as expected, which it is.  On our production box, however, developers aren't allowed to modify data or to run any procedures, and thus I can't use DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL to get the DDL and, hence, to determine the INTERVAL set on the production DB.  Could someone provide an idea of how to find the value used in the INTERVAL clause when the production table was built by querying system tables or views?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get select access to dba_part_tables (for 11gr2):

```
select interval from dba_part_tables where table_name = 'SOME_TABLE' and owner = 'SOME_OWNER';
```